# Algorithm to produce a clean __str__ method for a tree

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I have a `Tree` class which is made up of `Node` objects. Each `Node` has the following instance vairables:

- `name`: string name of the node
- `depth`: int of the depth of the node in the tree (root has depth 0)
- `parent`: reference to the parent `Node` object (root's parent is `None`)
- `children`: list of all child `Node` objects (leaves have an empty list)

The `Node` class also has a method `get_ancenstors()` which returns a list of the `Node`s in the path from this `Node`'s parent to the root.

The tree is built using a recursive function and has the following instance variables:

- `root`: reference to the root `Node`
- `leaves`: list of all leaf `Node`s

The `Tree` class has a method `dfs()` which performs a depth first search/traversal of the tree and yields every `Node` visited. It also has a `__str__()` method as such:

```
def __str__(self):
    string = ''
    for dir in self.dfs(self.root):
        # TODO: Create branches as '|-' 
        branches = ('  ' * (dir.depth))
        string += f'{branches}{dir.name}\n'
    return string
```

Which produces an ouput like:

```
Dir 1
  Dir 2
    Dir 3
  Dir 4
    Dir 5
      Dir 6
      Dir 7
    Dir 8
  Dir 9
    Dir 10
```

Instead, I want a visually cleaner, but more complex implementation of this `__str__()` method which produces an output like this:

```
Dir 1
|--- Dir 2
|    |--- Dir 3
|
|--- Dir 4
|    |--- Dir 5
|    |    |--- Dir 6
|    |    |--- Dir 7
|    |
|    |--- Dir 8
|
|--- Dir 9
     |--- Dir 10
     |--- Dir 11
          |--- Dir 12
```

Can anyone help with the logic behind this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following solution with specific formatting logic:

```
def __str__(self):
    string = ''
    for dir in self.dfs(self.root):
        branches, depth = '', dir.depth
        if depth > 0:
            branches = '|--- '  # initial (closest) dashed block
            branches = '|    ' * (depth - 1) + branches
        string += f'{branches}{dir.name}\n'
    return string
```

---

Simplified test case for demo:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Node = namedtuple('Node', 'name depth')
dfs = [Node(f'Dir{i+1}', depth=i) for i in range(4)]

def n__str__(dfs):
    string = ''
    for dir in dfs:
        branches, depth = '', dir.depth
        if depth > 0:
            branches = '|--- '  # initial (closest) dashed block
            branches = '|    ' * (depth - 1) + branches
        string += f'{branches}{dir.name}\n'
    return string

print(n__str__(dfs))
```

The output:

```
Dir1
|--- Dir2
|    |--- Dir3
|    |    |--- Dir4
```

Answer (score -1):

A possibility is to create a recursive generator that yields a complete row for every child. Then, in `__str__`, you can simply use `str.join`:

```
class Tree:
   ...
   def to_dir(self, d = 0, flag=True):
      if flag:
        yield self.name if not d else '|'+"|".join(["\t"]*(d-1))+f'{"|"*(bool(d-1))}--- {self.name}'
      else:
         yield "".join(["\t"]*(d-1))+f'{"|"*(not d)}{"|"*(bool(d))}--- {self.name}'
      for i, a in enumerate(self.children):
         yield from a.to_dir(d=d+1, flag = falg)
   def __str__(self):
      return '\n'.join(self.to_dir())
```

---

Example:

```
class Tree:
   def __init__(self, n, c):
      self.name, self.children = n, c
   def to_dir(self, d = 0, flag=True): 
      if flag:
         yield self.name if not d else '|'+"|".join(["\t"]*(d-1))+f'{"|"*(bool(d-1))}--- {self.name}'
      else:
         yield "".join(["\t"]*(d-1))+f'{"|"*(not d)}{"|"*(bool(d))}--- {self.name}'
      for i, a in enumerate(self.children):
         yield from a.to_dir(d=d+1, flag=False if not flag else i != len(self.children)-1)
   def __str__(self):
      return '\n'.join(self.to_dir())

t = Tree('Dir 1', [Tree('Dir 2', [Tree('Dir 5', [])]), Tree('Dir 3', []), Tree('Dir 4', [Tree('Dir 6', [Tree('Dir 7', [])])])])
```

Output:

```
Dir 1
|--- Dir 2
       |--- Dir 5
|--- Dir 3
|--- Dir 4
       |--- Dir 6
              |--- Dir 7
```